# React-Native drawable error when building the Android app

Tags: android, react-native

I'm building the app for release using this command: **./gradlew assembleRelease**, but I'm getting this error:

```
uncaught error Error: Don't know which android drawable suffix to use for asset: {"__packager_asset":true,"fileSystemLocation":"/home/marco/Lavoro/react/FarEast/img","httpServerLocation":"/assets/img","width":140,"height":83,"scales":[1,2,3,4,5],"files":["/home/marco/Lavoro/react/FarEast/img/main_halfcard_upper@1x.png","/home/marco/Lavoro/react/FarEast/img/main_halfcard_upper@2x.png","/home/marco/Lavoro/react/FarEast/img/main_halfcard_upper@3x.png","/home/marco/Lavoro/react/FarEast/img/main_halfcard_upper@4x.png","/home/marco/Lavoro/react/FarEast/img/main_halfcard_upper@5x.png"],"hash":"1d3f184ba6cf0e73bee648bb6b5aea53","name":"main_halfcard_upper","type":"png"}
at Object.getAndroidDrawableFolderName (assetPathUtils.js:25:11)
at getAssetDestPathAndroid (getAssetDestPathAndroid.js:15:40)
at saveAssets.js:38:44
at Array.forEach (native)
at saveAssets.js:36:20
at Array.forEach (native)
at saveAssets (saveAssets.js:35:6)
at buildBundle.js:65:29
at tryCallOne (/home/marco/Lavoro/react/FarEast/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
at /home/marco/Lavoro/react/FarEast/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently I was using the wrong tag to indicate the sizes of the images.

This is the correct approach (taken from *assetPathUtils.js*)

```
case 0.75: return 'ldpi';
case 1: return 'mdpi';
case 1.5: return 'hdpi';
case 2: return 'xhdpi';
case 3: return 'xxhdpi';
case 4: return 'xxxhdpi';
```

So *image@1.5x.png* matches native *ldpi*,
*image@1x.png* matches native *mdpi* and so on.

Comment: Thanks, also you need exactly these. I had a 5x and it was giving the error too.

Answer (score 3):

I got the following similar error using the ldpi phone(emulator), but in my `./img` folder there is no `./img/green-apple@0.75.png` image:

```
uncaught error Error: Don't know which android drawable suffix to use for asset: {"__packager_asset":true,"fileSystemLocation":"/Users/vasavi/dev/prashanthWorkspace/dev/img","httpServerLocation":"/assets/img","width":34,"height":38,"scales":[0.5,1,1.5,2,3],"files":["/Users/vasavi/dev/prashanthWorkspace/dev/img/green-apple@0.5x.png","/Users/vasavi/dev/prashanthWorkspace/dev/img/green-apple@1x.png","/Users/vasavi/dev/prashanthWorkspace/dev/img/green-apple@1.5x.png","/Users/vasavi/dev/prashanthWorkspace/dev/img/green-apple@2x.png","/Users/vasavi/dev/prashanthWorkspace/dev/img/green-apple@3x.png"],"hash":"f017f83c41b557cf3c65663d7f4f0583","name":"green-apple","type":"png"}
    at Object.getAndroidDrawableFolderName (assetPathUtils.js:25:11)
    at getAssetDestPathAndroid (getAssetDestPathAndroid.js:15:40)
    at saveAssets.js:38:44
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at saveAssets.js:36:20
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at saveAssets (saveAssets.js:35:6)
    at buildBundle.js:72:29
    at tryCallOne (/Users/vasavi/dev/prashanthWorkspace/dev/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
    at /Users/vasavi/dev/prashanthWorkspace/dev/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
```

The solution is: if you are using

- **ldpi device** you should have the image like `./img/green-apple@0.75.png` or
- **mdpi device** you should have the image like `./img/green-apple@1.png` or
- **hdpi device** you should have the image like `./img/green-apple@1.5.png` or
- **xhdpi device** you should have the image like `./img/green-apple@2.png` or
- **xxhdpi device** you should have the image like `./img/green-apple@3.png` or
- **xxxhdpi device** you should have the image like `./img/green-apple@4.png`.

Answer (score 0):

In My case I was using the Images like

```
group-img.png
group-img@4x.png
group-img@6x.png
```

Then I change it like

```
group-img.png
group-img@2x.png
group-img@3x.png
```

And it start working

This can cause problem into the following

1. **./gradlew assembleRelease**
2. **./gradlew clean**
3. **./gradlew assembleDebug**